# Standalone Java EE Application Server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jetty, application-server

I am developing standalone application.

Application is started like `java -jar myapp.jar` and is not deployed anywhere. I need to use an embeddable application server.

So far I found only [Jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/), but it doesn't support all Java EE features. Is there any other alternatives?

Comment: Jetty has an [jetty-ejb](https://github.com/jetty-project/jetty-ejb) module which provides the same Java EE layers as TomEE.  However, its not a very popular module (less than 200 total downloads).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely go with [tomee](http://tomee.apache.org/index.html). basically it's tomcat with bit of steroid of j2ee :p

=============

These are the code, I tested it in my local laptop and it should works. Note that you need to download the tomee-embedded.jar from this [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/tomee/tomee-embedded-1.5.0.jar.zip) and also the source code for the embedded jar can be found in [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomee/tomee/trunk/tomee/tomee-embedded/) if you want to understand what exactly happen in the code.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer;

import org.apache.openejb.loader.IO;
import org.apache.tomee.embedded.EmbeddedTomEEContainer;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    EJBContainer container = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("Start");
        final File war = createWar();
            final Properties p = new Properties();
            p.setProperty(EJBContainer.APP_NAME, "test");
            p.setProperty(EJBContainer.PROVIDER, EmbeddedTomEEContainer.class.getName());
            p.put(EJBContainer.MODULES, war.getAbsolutePath());
            p.setProperty(EmbeddedTomEEContainer.TOMEE_EJBCONTAINER_HTTP_PORT, "-1");

            System.out.println(war.getAbsolutePath());

            container = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(p);
            System.out.println(container);
            System.out.println(container.getContext());
            final URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:" + System.getProperty(EmbeddedTomEEContainer.TOMEE_EJBCONTAINER_HTTP_PORT) + "/test/index.html");
            System.out.println(getOk(url, 2));

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.err.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

            if (container != null) {
                container.close();
            }
        }
    }
    private static String getOk(final URL url, final int tries) throws Exception {
        try {
            return IO.readProperties(url).getProperty("ok");
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            if (tries > 0) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                return getOk(url, tries - 1);
            } else {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }

    private static File createWar() throws IOException {
        final File file = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "/tomee-" + Math.random());
        if (!file.mkdirs() && !file.exists()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("can't create " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        write("ok=true", new File(file, "index.html"));
        write("<beans />", new File(file, "WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/beans.xml"));
        return file;
    }

    private static void write(final String content, final File file) throws IOException {
        if (!file.getParentFile().mkdirs() && !file.getParentFile().exists()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("can't create " + file.getParent());
        }

        final FileWriter index = new FileWriter(file);
        index.write(content);
        index.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to find any embedded example with tomee like jetty has http://eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedded-examples.html , but can't find any :(

Comment: later, i'll try to update the answer with the code on how to run tomee embedded. as for now, maybe you could see this [test case](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomee/tomee/trunk/tomee/tomee-embedded/src/test/java/org/apache/tomee/embedded/ClasspathAsWebappTest.java). the key is in the method deployPathsAsWebapp() ;)

Comment: https://tomee.apache.org/advanced/tomee-embedded/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Look into the spring-boot project:

http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/

It provides features for building executable jars with embedded application servers.  Grizzly, Jetty, Tomcat and Undertow are options.  The spring-boot project itself provides various additional support such as built in metrics and health checks out of the box.  Hopefully one of the provided application servers meets your needs.

Undertow (http://undertow.io/) supposedly can be a full Java EE servlet 3.1 container, but I have not personally worked with it yet.  Every project I have worked on found Jetty and/or Tomcat to be sufficient.